# Phantoms and Selenium usage

Tags: selenium, phantomjs

I know there have been already many posts related to this topic, however even I search and read most of them, I still have some questions.

Seems like that: Phantoms is a browser(just without a GUI so you can not see it) and Selenium is your hands used to control the browser.

If that is true, so what is the difference between visiting a page in Phantoms and visiting a page in Selenium by PhantomJSDriver? Does the later make the interaction more human-like? For example, open a page, scroll the page and move to a certain link, click it-open url in a new window(tab), move out the current page, operate in the new page and etc. Does the above operations can be implemented, even with the focus/hover/mouseover/mouseout event and  mousemove track?

Furthermore, is it possible to avoid the website server detect that the browser is real rather than headless? I do not think changing the user-agent string is enough, since the site can run javascript in the client which can detects the browser-specified features.

Comment: selenium is a package that allow you to use different webdrivers (among many other scraping functions), both actual ones such as `chrome` or `Firefox` and headless ones such as Phantoms

Comment: *"Selenium is your hands used to control the browser."* - Where did you read that? You still have to write code, so that's about the extent that your hands control the browser.